# Getting started with blackberry Push notification

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-webworks

Where do I register with RIM to get push notifications in my app? Are there other alternatives apart from urbanairship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to get the push notifications for your blackberry application , you need to register the application in RIM for receiving the application Id and other credentials.

If you are looking for a sample code to implement push registration from device,check the link below :
[Simplified BIS-Push client sample](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857)

You could use xtify instead of urbanarirship. try this [Xtify](http://www.xtify.com/)